# Jquery checkboxes return some values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have list of checkboxes and I need to get an array of checked items. I use the following function, but it returns some character values also.

```
var rIds = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function (_, el) {
    return $(el).val();
}).get();
```

Output is:

```
["1", "414", "true", "true"]
```

However I expect the below output,

```
["1", "414"]
```

Why is this?

Comment: Your function is correct. If you're selecting more checkboxes than you expect then you need to make your `'input[type=checkbox]:checked'` selector more specific

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you beat me by 10 secs. Also @ TechGuy, you should use something like `containerSelector input[type=checkbox]:checked`

Comment: use  `rIds.slice(0,2)`

Comment: @madalinivascu that's a very bad idea

Comment: it is saying "Output is: " not "output is like "

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant. My point is that simply removing the last two elements of the resulting array is a very rigid 'band-aid' solution. What happens if the code runs on another page where there is three extra checkboxes? What happens if there's no extra checkboxes? It's better to fix the selector to only retrieve the checkboxes you intend to capture.

Comment: Why have you tagged `C#`? Question has nothing to do with it

Comment: What is the first parameter `_` for ? just `el` is enough .

Comment: @RoyiNamir No. he is using `$.map` and not `array.map`. first param is index and second is element

Comment: @Rajesh yes. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

> Number() will only return number if it is number otherwise `0 ,Infinity , NaN` will return

```
var rIds = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function (_, el) {
    var current = $(el).val();
    if (Number(current) == current) return current ; 
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @[Rory Mccrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan), your selector will fetch all checkboxes. You should rather update your selector to get proper elements.

Following is a basic implementation showing both cases:

```js
$("#btnTest").on("click", function() {
  var allChks = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map((i, v) => v.value).get();
  var div2Chks = $(".container2 input[type=checkbox]:checked").map((i, v) => v.value).get();
  console.log(allChks, div2Chks)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
  <input type="checkbox" value="true" checked>Test
  <input type="checkbox" value="true" checked>Test
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="foo" checked>Foo
  <input type="checkbox" value="bar" checked>Bar
</div>

<button id="btnTest">Get Value</button>
```